Flutter didChangeAppLifecycleState is not working
didChangeAppLifecycleState is not working. I have checked all other question related to this, but not helpful.
    @override
    void initState() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
      super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
      // TODO: implement didChangeAppLifecycleState
      UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "Before");
      print(state);
      UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "After");
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        //TODO: set status to online here in firestore
        UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "Online");
        UpFirebaseDB.updateUserStatus(status: true);
      } else {
        //TODO: set status to offline here in firestore
        UpFirebaseDB.updateUserStatus(status: false);
        UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "Offline");
      }
    }

Note: I have used the initialRoute: '/', onGenerateRoute: UpRoutes.onGenerateRoute, for page navigation and i'm using the Getx for state management.
Thank in Advanced.

Did you wrap your MaterialApp in main.dart with LifeCycleManager or whatever the class you defined the provided code is in is called?

Unsure about the setup of your application but I can provide you with the base code that works on my end.
First, create a lifecylce_manager.dart file which includes:
class LifeCycleManager extends StatefulWidget {
final Widget child;
const LifeCycleManager({super.key, required this.child});

@override
LifeCycleManagerState createState() => LifeCycleManagerState();
}

class LifeCycleManagerState extends State<LifeCycleManager>
  with WidgetsBindingObserver {

@override
void initState() {
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
 super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  super.dispose();
}

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  // TODO: implement didChangeAppLifecycleState
  UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "Before");
  print(state);
  UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "After");
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    //TODO: set status to online here in firestore
    UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "Online");
    UpFirebaseDB.updateUserStatus(status: true);
  } else {
    //TODO: set status to offline here in firestore
    UpFirebaseDB.updateUserStatus(status: false);
    UpPrint(name: "CheckUserStatus", value: "Offline");
  }
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: widget.child,
  );
 }
}

Then, in the main.dart file or your applications entry point:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return LifeCycleManager(
    child: MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: UpRoutes.onGenerateRoute,
      theme: appTheme(),
    ),
  );
 }
}


Make sure that you have initialized WidgetsFlutterBinding in your main() function, ensuring that your Flutter app is properly set up to handle lifecycle events.
ex:
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


Thanks for response, but already did it.
